# "Direction opposite of" or "opposite direction of?"

Tags: word-order

Is one of these sentences wrong, or are they all correct, and why? Which is easiest to parse?

> The man signaled with a tilt of his head in the opposite direction of the
>   club.
>
> The man signaled with a tilt of his head in the direction opposite of the
>   club.
>
> The man signaled with a tilt of his head in the direction opposite the
>   club.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two read wrong, because they imply that the club has a direction.  But clubs are just places, they don't have a direction.  However, you *can* have a direction **to** the club.

So replacing "of" with "to" in the first two examples would make more sense.  "opposite the club" is a common contraction of "opposite to the club", so the third makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

"Opposite to" seems like an oxymoron, in my opinion.  I agree with everything Simon B said, except I would say "opposite from" the club.  I don't know if it really makes a difference, though.